# Como hacer un merge de commits especificos

Tags: git

Tengo un proyecto llamado `Proyect` que posee tres (**3**) ramas:

1. `master` (***M***)
2. `sdev` (***S***)
3. `test` (***T***)

Las cuales en estos momentos están así:

```
initial commit
↓   
↓   
↓      merge test into master
↓      checkout -b sdev master
↓      ↓ 
↓      ↓

M------*------------------------------* # HEAD
\     / \ 
 \   /   \
  \ /     \
   T-------\--------\--------------*    # commits behind master
            \        \
             \        \
              S-*--*---*---------*      # commits behind test behind master

                ↑  ↑   ↑
                ↑  ↑   ↑         
                ↑  ↑   ↑
                ↑  ↑   merge test into sdev           
                ↑  ↑ 
                ↑  ↑
                ↑  commit 2 que quiero pushear directamente a master
                ↑
                ↑
                commit 1 que quiero pushear directamente a master
```

Lo que deseo hacer y desconozco es realizar un `merge` especifico del `commit 1` y el `commit 2` de la rama `sdev` directamente a la rama `master` sin afectar nada en los `commits` posteriores de las ramas `sdev` y `test`, osea, quisiera algo así:

```
M------*------------------------------*-*--* # HEAD
\     / \             ________________↑ ↑
 \   /   \           / _________________↑
  \ /     \         / /
   T-------\-------*-*------------------*    # commits behind master
            \     / / 
             \   / /      
              S-*--*---*--------------*      # commits behind test behind master
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplemente tenía que hacer uso de [**git cherry-pick**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

**Primero**: me pasé a la rama `sdev` con un simple `git checkout sdev`

**Segundo**: busqué los identificadores únicos `SHA-1` de los commit de la rama `sdev` con un simple:
 `git log --pretty=oneline`, el cual me arrojó:

```
<SHA-1> (origin/sdev) commit 1
<SHA-1> (origin/sdev) commit 2
```

**Tercero**: me volví a pasar a la rama `master` (la cual es donde quería realizar el `merge`)
**Cuarto**: Luego procedí a realizar el *cherry-pick*

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>
```

> Todo OK, sin ningún problema y/o conflictos

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>
```

> Aquí se me presentó un conflicto en varios archivos
>   Lo solucioné manualmente y procedí con

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

El *cherry-pick* puede ser cancelado agregando la opción `--abort`